# What is the MongoDb connection string required for Azure CosmosDb Emulator Task in Build Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am trying to use the new Azure CosmosDB Emulator Task (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-setup-ci-cd).

We are relying on the Azure CosmosDb support for MongoDb and I can't seem to figure out what the connection string should be. In the above example the Endpoint URL is over written by the Output variable provided by the CosmosDb Emulator task -- but that is not in the expected format.

Edit: The default connection string for mongodb is not working

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/connect-mongodb-account), the connection string for emulator is:

```
mongodb://localhost:C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==@localhost:10255/admin?ssl=true
```

Comment: Yes in a normal case that would be true.. but when you run the emulator as a task in the build pipeline that connection string does not work.